# How to search attribute in XML file in ActionScript3 using regex?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I have a xml file like this :

```
<data>
<season id="00">
    <project id="text"/>
    <project id="test"/>
    <project id="move"/>
    <project id="moser"/>
    <project id="moment"/>
    <project id="save"/>
    <project id="safe"/>
    <project id="search"/>      
</season>
<season id="01">
    <project id="send"/>
    <project id="serve"/>
    <project id="service"/>
    <project id="mondey"/>
    <project id="mother"/>
    <project id="tesla"/>
    <project id="tiser"/>
    <project id="spacnk"/>      
</season>
```

I want to find xmllist with regexp for match some text in attributes for example "se" or "mo".
Please help me.

Comment: Do not use a regular expression to search XML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var xml:XML = 
<data>
    <season id="00">
        <project id="text"/>
        <project id="test"/>
        <project id="move"/>
        <project id="moser"/>
        <project id="moment"/>
        <project id="save"/>
        <project id="safe"/>
        <project id="search"/>
    </season>
    <season id="01">
        <project id="send"/>
        <project id="serve"/>
        <project id="service"/>
        <project id="mondey"/>
        <project id="mother"/>
        <project id="tesla"/>
        <project id="tiser"/>
        <project id="spacmonk"/>
    </season>
</data>;

trace( xml..project.( @id.match( /se/ ) ).toXMLString() );
```

Explanation:

```
xml     // using the XML data in our xml variable
..      // find descendants at any level
project // that is an element of type project
(       // open an expression to evaluate
@id     // using attribute 'id' of our project elements
.match( // find matching 'id' values using regular expression
/se/    // find the string 'se' anywhere in the string that is evaluated
)       // close match()
)       // close expression
```

To match only project elements with id attributes that start with "se" you simply have to alter the regular expression as usual:

```
/^se/
```

And ending with "se":

```
/se$/
```

... etc.

Comment: thank fireeyedboy,but this code in some problem,becuse xml list return only when result in greater than 1 item,and when result equal one item (for example when i search test , xml list in not return) please test this code

Comment: @user1009898: I've edited my answer. The single XML element is in the result, but `toString()` only outputs complex content. Use [`toXMLString()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XMLList.html#toXMLString()) to view the simple content as well. If you issue `length()` on the result `XMLList` you will see there is 1 element in the `XMLList`. For more info see the [documentation on `XMLList`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XMLList.html)